# Getting stock quote with JavaScript though yahoo's webservices

Tags: javascript, web-services, rest, yahoo-finance

I need to create a simple web site that gets the stock value based on the ticket. 
Input: CSCO Output: 23.49. I'm very new to both webservices and javascript. The current YQL statement I am using is: `select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol="CSCO"` which does not work.

```
function getprice()
{


  var symbol = $('#stockquote').val();


var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22"+symbol+"%22)%0A%09%09&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&format=json";

$.getJSON(url, function (json)
{

    var lastquote = json.query.results.quote.LastTradePriceOnly;
    $('#stock').text(lastquote);

});
}
```

Comment: [Your code works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/m3h8b/)

Comment: Your url works: [link](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22CSCO%22)%0A%09%09&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&format=json)

Comment: Well this sucks then still can't get a result for the url thanks for testing it though.